# Is there an exclusive creation mode for sqlite3.connect in Python? (create file ONLY if it doesn't already exist)

Tags: python, sqlite

In Python 3, the open function has the handy `"x"` mode (for "exclusive create") that tries to make a new file and raises a `FileExistsError` if there's already a file with the given name. I'd like to do something similar with a sqlite3 database.

The default behavior for `sqlite3.connect` is to connect to an existing file (if there is a file with the given name), and to create a new one (if there is no file with the given name). I know that if you use a URI, you can add a mode, but as far as I can tell, the only available modes are `ro` (read only), `rw` (read and write), `rwc` (the default read/write/create-if-it-doesn't-exist mode), and `memory` (definitely not relevant here).

I could just try to open the file using `rw` mode and raise an error if that succeeds, or I could check if the file exists using `os.path.exists`... But as I understand it, this is not ideal because a file could be created after the check but before the new database file is created.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

The only open modes supported by the C [`sqlite3_open_v2()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) function are the ones you already described. The underlying virtual file system framework that's used for the actual low level file operations *does* support an exclusive open flag, but that functionality is not provided by the public API.

The documentation even notes

> Note in particular that the `SQLITE_OPEN_EXCLUSIVE` flag is a no-op for `sqlite3_open_v2()`. The `SQLITE_OPEN_EXCLUSIVE` does *not* cause the open to fail if the database already exists. The `SQLITE_OPEN_EXCLUSIVE` flag is intended for use by the VFS interface only, and not by `sqlite3_open_v2()`.

so I suspect people have tried to do this before.